# Chrome doesn't use swap

Tags: linux, google-chrome, memory, swap

I have written a single page application that gradually loads objects, and memory usage increases.

At a certain point, Google Chrome shows an error page, and from the log I see

```
[1:1:1210/224428.169664:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(42)] Out of memory
```

However, (I'm under linux) from `free` I see that the RAM is actually filled up, but swap is free. So, why Chrome doesn't continue to work as usual?

Comment: On modern OSes, RAM is pretty much always filled up. There's always something you can use it for -- disk cache if nothing else. And how much swap is used or free is not really relevant -- what matters is how much swap might be needed. If that exceeds the swap available -- even if no swap is actually used -- then allocations will fail.

Comment: I think chrome should need another 200 or 400 megabytes, and there are 7 gigabytes of free swap, so I don't understand why it is not used

Comment: Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit build of Chrome? It may be out of process address space.

Comment: I'm using Version 71.0.3578.80 Official Build (64 bit). It seems to me that sometimes chrome crashes even before RAM is filled up

Comment: The term "RAM is filled up" is really a meaningless one that you should stop using. Your issue has nothing to do with whether or not RAM is filled up but with whether memory is available for allocation which is almost entirely unrelated. For example, RAM can be empty but no memory available for allocations due to existing unshared, writable file mappings. Or RAM can be completely full of discardable pages and plenty of memory available for allocation. One has almost nothing to do with each other on a modern OS.

Comment: You are right. However, I see chrome crashing when I see - for the swap - free 7000 from the `free` program (free -m). I tried with Firefox and this doesn't happen, i.e. also the swap gets used until it is not full.